# jQuery for each child checkbox in a paragraph id

Tags: jquery

How do I select each child checkbox inside a paragraph named id="Paragraph1" and uncheck it if its checked and then disable it in jQuery.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMain"><br />
<p id="Paragraph1">
    <input type="checkbox" id"chk1"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id"chk2"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id"chk3"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id"chk4"><br />
</p>
```

jQuery selection:

```
$("#chkMain:not(:checked)").change(function() {
    $("#Paragraph1").children("input[type='checkbox' :checked]").each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("checked").attr("disabled",disabled");     
    });
});
```

This code isn't working right b/c its only working half the time for some reason in IE8. Also using find is not working right either maybe b/c a paragraph is not a good parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input[type='checkbox' :checked]` is not correct selector.

It should be:

`input[type='checkbox']:checked`

And I think you can simplify the code like:

```
$('#Paragraph1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked')  // select all checked input
                    .removeAttr('checked')       // remove checked attribute
                    .prop('disabled', true);     // make em disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all this:

```
$("#Paragraph1").children("input[type='checkbox' :checked]").each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr("checked").attr("disabled",disabled");     
  });
```

With this:

```
 $("#Paragraph1 input[type='checkbox']:checked")
     .prop('checked', false)
     .prop('disabled', true);
```

- You should use `each` when you want to do something that isn't available with jQuery API on every element in the set, like `alert` or send AJAX request.
- Use `prop` when you can, don't mess with the attributes.
- space in a CSS selector means "children of", so remove the space of `:checked` and add a space between the Paragraph1 and the input. for direct child you can use `parent > children`

Like with this:

```
$("#Paragraph1 > input[type='checkbox']:checked")
     .prop('checked', false)
     .prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Does this work for jQuery-1.7.2.js?  Not able to get this to work yet.  Plus I don't see .prop as an actual function.

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntax errors in your code, you can use `prop` method:

```
$("#chkMain").change(function() {
     $("#Paragraph1 input[type='checkbox']")
              .prop('checked', this.checked) 
              .prop('disabled', !this.checked)
});
```